# Tagging Data from Tagging table(status,timestamp) to the main table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table called tagging with columns machine_id,status,date.
and one main table called telemetry with columns id,machine_id,telemetry_time,riskscore,current.

status column contains only 'normal' or 'abnormal'.
we are storing data,when tagging is done with corresponding status and date.
from here I want to tag this data to my telemetry table.

here is my example tables and expected output .

Can any one please help me.

[check this link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=455ab7a566c71ca8bc1b4da2731e373b)

Expected output:

if i select data between '2020-10-01' and '2020-10-20' from telemetry_uday table.
i need o/p as below by tagging status column from  tagging_uday table to telemetry_table

```
('2020-10-01 10:10:00',2,1.4,21.'normal'),
('2020-10-01 11:10:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-01 12:10:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-01 13:00:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-02 09:10:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-02 10:10:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-02 10:20:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-02 11:12:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-02 11:40:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-15 10:10:00',2,1.4,21,'abnormal'),
('2020-10-15 11:10:00',2,1.2,20,'abnormal'),
('2020-10-15 12:10:00',2,1.2,20,'abnormal'),
('2020-10-16 01:00:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-16 09:10:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-16 10:10:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-16 10:20:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-16 11:12:00',2,1.2,20,'normal'),
('2020-10-16 11:40:00',2,1.2,20,'normal')
```

Comment: added  in the question it self @Akina

Comment: Im newbie to this community,please dont mine by my question formation @Akina

Comment: Sorry im missed that 1.2,20 value,while editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place to use a *lateral join*:

```
select tu.*, t.status
from telemetry_uday tu left join lateral
     (select t.*
      from tagging_uday t
      where t.equipment_id = tu.equipment_id and
            t.date <= tu.telemetry_time
      order by t.date desc
      limit 1
     ) t
     on 1=1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a2f5b360294b9bd661a9335484a0b283) is a db<>fiddle.

Note the results are slightly different from what is given in your answer.  In particular, `2020-10-15 12:10:00` is normal and `2020-10-16 13:00:00` is abnormal.

This is consistent with the data you have provided, so I think the results in the question are slightly off.

Comment: @udaygalidevara . . . This should be much more efficient than an answer that uses `select distinct`, which is why I answered it.

Comment: Im Agree with you.Implemented and checked your solution.thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*,
                FIRST_VALUE(t2.status) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t2."date" DESC) status
FROM telemetry_uday t1
JOIN tagging_uday t2 ON t2.equipment_id = t1.equipment_id
                    AND t2."date" <= t1.telemetry_time
ORDER BY telemetry_time;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8975c369fade9e11394a0aad94cdc86a)